# Spring component returning list from previous run

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, spring-bean

I have a spring component which looks like this. It has other beans auto-wired to it. And these components are returned as a list by the method `getConfigurators(String Id)`

```
@Component
public class Configuration{

    @Autowired
    private  Config Config1;
    @Autowired
    private  Config Config2;

    @Override
    public List<Config> getConfigurators(String Id) {
        return List.of(
                Config1,
                Config2);
       }
     }
```

When I run the application the first time, I get everything correct for `getConfigurators(String Id)`. The subsequent runs, I get the values populated by the first run. I want that every time I run the application, the list is not pre populated with the config values from before.

The Config class looks like this

```
@Component
public class Config1 implements Config {
 final List errors = new ArrayList<>();
   @Override
    public List<> validate() {
        boolean isValid // some logic
        if (!isValid) {
            errors.add("Some error");
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the values in Config? How does the Config class look like?

Comment: yes the config values

Comment: In Spring, beans (instances of classes managed by Spring) are Singleton by default and only once instantiated.

That's why you always get the same result. Without knowing what you are trying to do it's hard to help